# How to draw the cartesian product of two infinite sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If I have sets A and B with the cardinality of the set of Integers, making these sets denuermable sets by definition, how could they be drawn?

I have a rough idea as it would look like ordered pairs, just like a coordnate for a 2D grid, inside a little box surrounded by multiple boxes going in all directions holding different ordered pairs.

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a [square lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_lattice)... but I can't be sure what you're getting at.

Comment: Why wouldn't the be drawn the same way $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ would?  You have an $x$ axis with all elements of $A$ listed in some order and a $y$ axiss with all the elements of $B$ listed in some order and the each element $(a,b)$ in the  where the line paralell to the $y$ axis at $a$ on the $x$ axis intersets the line paralel to $x$ axis and $b$ on the $y$ axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List A as $a_1, a_2, a_3, ...$ and B as $b_1, b_2, b_3, ....$

Place for all positive integers k, $a_k$ on (k,0) and $b_k$ on (0,k).
You will see A laided out as positive integers on the x-axis
and B laided out as positive integers on the x-axis.

Consequently you'll see AxB laided out as all the
points (n,m) on the plane with positive integers n,m.